# Issue chaining data with handlebars

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

Im having issues displaying data that Im rendering to my view file.

The data i'm receiving from the data is structured like so:

```
[ {
    id: 1,
    first_name: 'Josh',
    last_name: 'Spears',
    occupation: 'Front End Developer' },
  {
    id: 2,
    first_name: 'Jesse',
    last_name: 'Bulpitt',
    occupation: 'Dev Ops Engineer' },
  {
    id: 3,
    first_name: 'James',
    last_name: 'Feigel',
    occupation: 'Sr. Front End Developer' },
  {
    id: 4,
    first_name: 'Chris',
    last_name: 'Harrell',
    occupation: 'Sr. Back End Developer' } ]
```

In my routes im rendering the data:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', devMembers = {
      allMembers : membersData.getAll()
  });
});
```

Where I get lost is in my view.

```
{{#each this}}
    <tr>
        <td class="id">{{id}}</td>
        <td>{{first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{occupation}}</td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

The each loop is iterating the correct amount of the itms in the array.. So I know it's not a asycn issue. My best guess is the way im chaining the data..

[image]

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try this  `<td class="id">{{this.id}}</td>`.. and so on

Comment: Yes. Still renders nothing.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to show the problem

Comment: it would be also helpful if you provided the code where you hook handlebars into express.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug this issue, is to use **`{{log this}}`** inside your each loop. And then, check in the console, the structure of your data.